# boost asio io_service::run() exits 'early' - or not?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

Can anyone tell me under what conditions `boost::asio`'s `io_service::run()` method will return? The documentation [documentation for `io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) seems to suggest that as long as there is work to be done or handlers to be dispatched, `run()` won't return.

The reason I'm asking this is that we have a legacy https client that contacts a server and executes http POST's. The separation of concerns in the client is a bit different than what we'd like so we're changing a few things about it, but we're running into problems.

Right now, the client basically has a mis-named `connect()` call that effectively drives the entire protocol conversation with the server. The `connect()` call starts off by creating a `boost::asio::ip::tcp::resolver` object and calling `::async_resolve()` on it. This starts a chain where new `asio` calls are made from within asio callbacks.

```
void connect()
{
    m_resolver.async_resolve( query, bind( &clientclass::resolve_callback, this ) );
    thread = new boost::thread( bind( &boost::asio::io_service::run, m_io_service ) );
}
void resolve_callback( error_code & e, resolver::iterator i )
{
    if (!e)
    { 
        tcp::endpoint = *i;
        m_socket.lowest_layer().async_connect(endpoint, bind(&clientclass::connect_callback,this,_1,++i));
    }
}
void connect_callback( error_code & e, resolve::iterator i )
{
    if (!e)
    { 
        m_socket.lowest_layer().async_handshake(boost::asio::ssl::stream_base::client,
            bind(&clientclass::handshake_callback,this,_1,++i));
    }
}
void handshake_callback( error_code &e )
{
    if (!e)
    {
        mesg = format_hello_message();
        http_send( mesg, bind(&clientlass::hello_resp_handler,this,_1,_2) );
    }
}
void http_send( stringstream & mesg, reply_handler handler )
{
    async_write(m_socket, m_request_buffer, bind(&clientclass::write_complete_callback,this,_1,handler));
}
void write_comlete_callback( error_code &e, reply_handler handler )
{
    if (!e)
    {
        async_read_until(m_socket,m_reply_buffer,"\r\n\r\n", bind(&clientclass::handle_reply,this,handler));
    }
}
...
```

Anyways, this continues through the protocol until the protocol conversation is done. From the code here you can see that while `connect()` is running on the main thread, all of the subsequent callbacks and requests are coming back on the worker thread that is created in `connect()`. This is 'working' code.

When I try to break this chain up and expose it via an external interface, it stops working. In particular, I'm having the call `handle_handshake()` call outside of the `clientclass` object. Then `http_send()` is part of the interface (or is called by the external interface) and it creates a new worker thread to call io_service::run(). What happens is even though `async_write()` has been called and even though `write_complete_callback()` hasn't returned, io_service::run() exits. It exits without error and claims that no handlers were dispatched, but there's still 'work' to be done?

So what I'm wondering is what is `io_service::run()`'s definition of 'work'? Is it a pending request? Why is it that `io_service::run()` never returns during this chain of requests and responses in the existing code, but when I try to start the thread up again and start a new chain, it returns almost immediately before it's finished its work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The definition of work in the context of the `run()` call is any pending asynchronous operations on that io_service object.  This includes the invocations of the handlers in response to an operation.  So, if a handler for one operation starts another operation, there is always work available.

In addition, there is an `io_service::work` class that can be used to create work on an io_service that never completes until the object is destroyed.

When a single chain completes, the io_service has completed all asynchronous operations, and all of the handler's have been invoked without starting a new operation, so it returns.  Until you call `io_service::reset()`, further calls to `run()` will return without executing any operations.

Comment: +1 The OP has very likely not called reset before the subsequent run

Comment: That was EXACTLY what I wasn't doing. I added the `::reset()` call and all is well now. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the `io_service::work` object. I couldn't figure out why my threads calling `io_context::run()` would exit before I called `io_context::stop()`. Seems like this defeats the purpose of having a thread pool.